# Android device with inverted x-axis and how to install new version of Android on the hardware device?

Tags: android, ubuntu, installation

At the moment I'm trying to tweak abbit with an hardware device running android.\

My problem at the moment is the `x-axis. It's inverted`, but the y-axis is not. So if I want to select something in the top left, I need to press top right. I tested the touchscreen on windows and it worked as it should. So the touchscreen is not the problem. Maybe I can `change some source code of android`, so I can invert the x-axis, and load it into the device.

`But what code do I have to change to invert the x-axis and how can I load a new version(for example Android 2.2) into the hardware device?` I can load apps with adb on the device. It only gives an error, because the app is allready installed.

It's a problem everywhere in Android. It's maybe possible that I only have to install android again, but as I said, I don't know how.

I'm working with:
* Ubuntu 11.10
* Android SDK
* Eclipse + ADT plugin